# Reading And Filtering a CSV files Column

Tags: python, pandas, google-colaboratory

I am reading a dataframe and finding the len using a condition like this:

```
import pandas as pd
gf = pd.read_csv(raw_github_csv_file_url)
print(len(gf[gf["gender"]=="M"]))
```

My CSV  has these columns:

id | profile | author | gender | flag
[image: same csv file]

But I am getting this error:

> > KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
> > /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in
> > get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)    3801             try:
> > -> 3802                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)    3803             except KeyError as err:
>
> 4 frames pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in
> pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()
>
> pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in
> pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()
>
> KeyError: 'gender'
>
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
>
> KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call
> last)
> /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in
> get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)    3802                 return
> self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)    3803             except KeyError
> as err:
> -> 3804                 raise KeyError(key) from err    3805             except TypeError:    3806                 # If we have a listlike key,
> _check_indexing_error will raise
>
> KeyError: 'gender'

I read other files in the same way and was successful but don't understand why I am getting error here. Or what is the root case.

Comment: Your example says "author".  I assume that was a typo.  You need to show us the first couple of line of the CSV file.  My guess it doesn't say what you think it does.  You are showing vertical bar separators instead of commas.  Which is it?

Comment: @TimRoberts, that's typo, corrected it. I was tried to access other columns too but getting same error. I have attached ss of the CSV file, can you please check

Comment: Yea, I messed up. Corrected

Comment: We don't need to see what it looks like in Excel.  We need to see the exact text, like in Notepad.

Comment: @TimRoberts, I never thought that excel and notepad looks are different. The real problem is separator `;` for this case which @Corralien has pointed out. Thanks for the pointer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have trailing spaces after column names. Try to strip them:

```
gf = pd.read_csv(raw_github_csv_fileurl)
gf.columns = gf.columns.str.strip()  # clean your column names
print(len(gf[gf["gender"]=="M"]))
```

To debug, try to print the column index:

```
print(gf.columns)
```

**Edit**

> Still getting the same issue. printing cols gives this: `Index(['id;"profile_link";"author";"gender";"flag"'], dtype='object')`

Your separator is wrong. The separator is not `','` but `';'`. Try:

```
# or sep=None, engine='python' to autodetect the separator
gf = pd.read_csv(raw_github_csv_fileurl, sep=';')
print(len(gf[gf["gender"]=="M"]))
```

Comment: Still getting the same issue. printing cols gives this: `Index(['id;"profile_link";"author";"gender";"flag"'], dtype='object')`

Comment: I updated my answer, can you check it please? The separator is probably `';'` and not `','`. If you have to read multiple files, I recommend you to use `sep=None` to let pandas guess the delimiter.